# List and jsons on Flutter request https

Tags: json, flutter, list

I hope you can help me, I have this json to send in a request

```
{
  "taxpayer": _person,
  "customerType": _dropdownTypeClient,
  "rfc": _rfc.text,
  "name": _name.text,
  "fatherSurname": _firstName.text,
  "motherSurname": _lastName.text,
  "businessName": _razonSocial.text,
  "contact": _contact.text,
  "phone": _phone.text,
  "cell": _cellphone.text,
  "taxRegime": _dropdownTax,
  "mailList": [
    {"mail": _email.text},
    {"mail": _emailTwo.text}
  ],
  "workType": _dropdownWorkType,
  "howToContact": _dropdownHowToContact
}
```

but i want to send the ***mailList*** as a real List, because th emailTwo is optional and when I send the information the DB counts the empty value. How i do the converse ? I tried this for simplicity but it didnt work.

```
//List mails = [];

//mails.add(_email.text);

//if (_emailTwo.text.isNotEmpty) {
//mails.add(_emailTwo.text);
//}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to know exactly why is your attempt "not working" without you giving the error messages. But we can guess, maybe you should try this:

```
List<dynamic> mails = [];

mails.add({"mail":_email.text});
final email2 = _emailTwo.text;
if (email2.isNotEmpty) {
  mails.add({"mail":email2 });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it reaaly works, sorry I forgot the problem of my attempt. My pc when blue screem and i just use an old one with less power. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `if` inside the map literal, like so:

```dart
{
  "mailList": [
    {"mail": _email.text},
    if (_emailTwo.text.isNotEmpty)
      {"mail": _emailTwo.text},
  ]
}
```

Comment: Wanna thank you! I help me with and update issue i haved on another request, that i use the same information.